# Personal practice of vipassana meditation

Tags: theravada

no rise of ill will towards other beings and  sankhara disappears  after samadhi nimitta has been seen. Sometimes when other person have scold ,dukka appear as a cloud and disappeared. What is the state of this?

Comment: Maybe this video can give you an idea of the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np5aYcZCEWo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You care too much of states and 'what is this, what is that'.
It's not necessary to know all this. There is too much wanting.

Whenever a question arises you should just say to yourself: wanting to know, wanting to know, wanting to know. Or just: wanting, wanting, wanting.
Get rid of all that desire.